# Given the matrices $[T]^\gamma_\beta$, $[S]^\beta_\gamma$, and the vector with a coordinate matrix $[v]_\beta$, find $(T\circ S)(v) $.

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the basis $\beta=\{(1,1), (1,-1)\}\subseteq \mathbb R^2$ and $\gamma=\{(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)\} \subseteq \mathbb R^3$

The linear transformations $T:\mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$, $S:\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^3$, are given in the form of:

$[T]^\gamma_\beta=\begin{bmatrix}3&-2&1\\4&1&-9\end{bmatrix}$ $[S]^\beta_\gamma=\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\2&7\\-3&11\end{bmatrix}$

Given that $T\circ S : \space \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$, determine the value of  $(T\circ S)(v) $.

$v \in \mathbb R^2 $, being the vector with the coordinate matrix of: $[v]_\beta=\begin{bmatrix}1\\-3\end{bmatrix}$

This seems like a rather trivial problem that I've been stuck a few days. I've would like some help in how to approach this.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.